# How to add 'a' link tag with hyperlink in Reactjs app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, jsx

I have some issue with add hyperlink to custom cell's text. I already add a tag into custom cell but as you see in code sandbox, It seems not working but still 'a' tag is exist inside the div tag.
How can I solve this problem?

Full Code and demo's are can acccess with codeSandbox

[Code SandBox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/sangumee/Crypto-Table/tree/master/?fontsize=14&module=%2Fsrc%2Fcomponents%2FtableSetting.js)

I use [React-data-table-component](https://github.com/jbetancur/react-data-table-component) and I followed the right way to add hyperlink but It seems it's not working. And I don't know why it's not working. It said it uses JSX.

```
const columns = [
  {
    name: 'Coin Name',
    selector: 'key',
    sortable: true,
    cell: row => (
      <a
        href={'https://www.bithumb.com/trade/order/' + row.key}
        target="_blank"
        rel="noopener noreferrer">
        {row.key}
      </a>
    ),
  },
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`React Data Table Component` by default has a column property called `ignoreRowClick` which is set to default to `false`. This helps in `onRowClicked` getting triggered unnecessarly. If you set `ignoreRowClick` to true, your `a` tag click will work.

```
{
    name: 'Coin Name',
    selector: 'key',
    sortable: true,
    ignoreRowClick: true,
    cell: row => (
      <a
        href={'https://www.bithumb.com/trade/order/' + row.key}
        target="_blank"
        rel="noopener noreferrer">
        {row.key}
      </a>
    ),
  },
```

Comment: A boolean cannot be set to 'no', the column is whether it's required or not, so that is written as 'no' in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The datatable is wrapping your `<a/>` tag with `div` and some other wrappers. When u click on the `<a/>` internally the click is not generated on that element but on its parent element (Parent element defines click on the entire row). If you try this

```
<a href={"https://www.bithumb.com/trade/order/" + row.key}
   target="_blank"
   rel="noopener noreferrer"
   style={{ position: "absolute" }}>
   {row.key}
</a>
```

It will work but this is not an optimised solution.
If you look into datatables docs you will find a property named `ignoreRowClick`. This will prevent the click event of entire row and activate click on specific column cell.

So the code will be

```
{
    name: "Coin Name",
    selector: "key",
    sortable: true,
    ignoreRowClick: true,  // This is the change
    cell: row => (
      <a
        href={"https://www.bithumb.com/trade/order/" + row.key}
        target="_blank"
        rel="noopener noreferrer"
        style={{ position: "absolute" }}
      >
        {row.key}
      </a>
    )
  },
```

Please read [Datatables](https://github.com/jbetancur/react-data-table-component#readme) docs for more

Answer (score 0):

Reacts DataTable component rows have their own click events and therefore cells are being covered by internal clip masks:

[image]